# do asyncio tasks have to be async all the way down?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I'm having problems wrapping an external task to parallelize it. I'm a newbie with asyncio so maybe I'm doing something wrong:

I have an `animate` method that I have also declared as async.
But that calls an external library that uses various iterators etc.
I'm wondering if something in a library is able to block asyncio at the top level?

`animate(item)` is a problem. if i define another async task it will run multiple calls concurrently and 'gather' later.

So am I doing it wrong, or is it possible the library been written such that it can't simply be parallelized with asyncio?
I also tried wrapping the call to `animate` with another async method, without luck.

```py
MAX_JOBS = 1  # how long for
ITEMS_PER_JOB = 4  # how many images per job/user request eg for packs

async def main():
    for i in range(0, MAX_JOBS):
        clogger.info('job index', i)
        job = get_next()
        await process_job(job)


async def process_job(job):
    batch = generate_batch(job)
    coros = [animate(item) for idx, item in enumerate(batch)]
    asyncio.gather(*coros)


asyncio.run(main())
```

the `animate` func has some internals and like

```
async def animate(options):

    for frame in tqdm(animator.render(), initial=animator.start_frame_idx, total=args.max_frames):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

OK NVM it seems all libraries have to be written with coroutines, but there are other options like

- [to_thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.to_thread)
- [run_in_executor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor)

not sure which is best in 2023 tho

[The tasks from asyncio.gather does not work concurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50215824/the-tasks-from-asyncio-gather-does-not-work-concurrently)