# Understanding Python async await coroutines (blocking loop example)

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I am trying to understand the coroutines. I know that they are using single thread and `await` keyword means "give back control to other running coroutines and give them a chance to run".

I have the following example:

```py
import asyncio
import time

async def long_function():
    # it takes almost 1 sec to execute it
    for _ in range(50000000):
        pass


async def count():
    for x in range(10):
        print(x)
        #await asyncio.sleep(0)
        await long_function()


async def gather():
    await asyncio.gather(count(), count())

asyncio.run(gather())
```

I would expect this code to run asynchronously and give the output like that:

```
0
0
1
1
2
2
...
```

However it gives:

```
0
1
2
3
...
0
1
2
3
...
```

When I uncomment the `asyncio.sleep(0)` the output is as expected - asynchronous.

Can anyone explain why is using `await long_function()` not enough to pass control to other coroutine? And how does it work on some lower level to help me understand.

Thank you.

Comment: `await long_function()` won't pass control to other coroutine because you don't await anything in `long_function()`

Comment: But it passes the control - that's exactly the reason you observe this behavior. Your problem is that `long_function` never releases that control. Try adding `await asyncio.sleep()` in `long_function`

Comment: This is quite similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50215824/the-tasks-from-asyncio-gather-does-not-work-concurrently

Answer (score 0):

When you uncomment await asyncio.sleep(0), it introduces a small pause, allowing the event loop to switch to other coroutines. This happens because await asyncio.sleep(0) is a non-blocking way to yield control to the event loop, allowing other tasks to run. It's a common trick to make long-running CPU-bound tasks cooperative by occasionally yielding control.

Here's a breakdown of what happens:

1. 'count' coroutine runs and prints 0.
2. await long_function() is called in count. Since long_function is CPU-bound and doesn't involve any I/O or asynchronous operations, it will run to completion without yielding control to the event loop.
3. While long_function is running, other coroutines (like the other count coroutine) are waiting for their turn, but they won't get it until long_function completes.
4. Uncommenting await asyncio.sleep(0) introduces a non-blocking sleep, allowing the event loop to switch to other coroutines during the long_function execution.

In general, if you're dealing with CPU-bound tasks and want to achieve parallelism, you might consider using "concurrent.futures" or other multiprocessing techniques. asyncio is more suited for I/O-bound tasks where coroutines can yield control willingly, allowing the event loop to switch to other tasks.

Answer (score 0):

After reading this helpful article:
https://bbc.github.io/cloudfit-public-docs/asyncio/asyncio-part-1
https://bbc.github.io/cloudfit-public-docs/asyncio/asyncio-part-2

I found out that I misunderstood the meaning of `await` keyword, as the behaviour of this keyword depends on the objects we are awaiting. There are three types of awaitable:

- Coroutine - when awaited, it gets added immediately to the execution stack, and it's executed, without yielding the control
- Future - when awaited, it depends on the state. If its FINISHED then it returns the result, if its NOT FINISHED, it gives back the control to the loop
- Task - inherits from Future

So the reason why my code was not running asynchronously is that I awaited a Coroutine, so it was added to the stack and executed.

Using `await asyncio.sleep(0)` was giving back the control, as `asyncio.sleep` uses Future underneath.

My original code can be rewritten to be asynchronous like this:

```py
import asyncio
import time

async def long_function():
    # it takes almost 1 sec to execute it
    for _ in range(50000000):
        pass


async def count():
    for x in range(10):
        print(x)
        task = asyncio.create_task(long_function())
        # awaiting the task causes the control to be given back
        await task


async def gather():
    await asyncio.gather(count(), count())


asyncio.run(gather())
```